# In which version did hibernate added support for jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Can anyone tell me which version of hibernate started supporting jpa

Answer (score 0):

According to hibernate wiki page:

> As of 2010, Hibernate 3 (version 3.5.0 and up) was a certified implementation of the Java Persistence API 2.0 specification via a wrapper for the Core module which provides conformity with the JSR 317 standard.

So I would say version 3.5.0 is the earliest version to support JPA.

Comment: Supported JPA Versions: [source](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) 
JPA 1.0: ORM 3.2+

JPA 2.0: ORM 3.5+

JPA 2.1: ORM 4.3+